# Design matrix web form with CiviCRM table

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform, civicrm, civicrm-extension

[image: Please open the Image to see my expected form]I am using Civicrm with drupal. Also using civicrm webfrom integration module for registration and/or data capturing requirement.

Now for a specific requirement, I need to develop a matrix kind of form. Means I want to show tabular form on screen. For each row of table there will be certain control which takes input from users and upon form submission (Save button click) it stores a record for each row in table.

Here, target table is from civicrm. I defined an activity with set of certain custom fields, so a new table has been created in civicrm database not in drupal site database, again this table have so many dependency with other civicrm tables.

I have came across certain module to matrix webform functionality but it works with drupal site database not with secondary database (here civicrm database is integrated with drupal).

Use of "views database connector" module provides access to civicrm tables in views but it is not helping with available matrix webform modules.

How this can be achievable? I have very little knowledge of core php.

Comment: I have read this twice now and still can't picture what you are trying to do. We have used Grid option successfully with civi entities in a webform in case that is a nudge in the right direction

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I have uploaded a picture of my expected output form. I have also mention tables details. Let me know how it is achievable. Thanks

Comment: if you were just using Activities and Custom Fields for those Activities you could possibly do this using Webform Grid and create/update multiple Activities when you submit form. But that doesn't sound like what you need. Perhaps Drupal Form is the route to go

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Can you please provide me some demo or some reference URL? so I can work on it.

Comment: If you mean for Drupal Forms, can't help much. Think this is where you might need to start https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x